# Managing multiple web servers for clients

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, ftp, clients

**I'm looking for a way to manage many combinations of FTP's, hosting company usernames and passwords, and what websites are on what web server.**

We manage 3 of our own web servers and some where around 20 client web servers (which is constantly growing). We have multiple sites on our web servers and some clients also have multiple sites their servers. So, we may have a server that has 10 sites with lots of different DB and several different FTP credentials.  Because we set up clients with their own hosting plan, we have alot of unique information about each website that we've ever done.

We've been using highrise and creating notes containing hosting logins, FTPs, and DB logins but we're losing alot of visibility. For example, how many clients are on media temple vs. dreamhost. How many clients are on media temple's GS vs. DV and so on. Finding FTP information based on the client or the website URl, and so on.

Does anyone know of a good tool to manage many different web servers?

Answer (score 4):

I've just started getting into hosting and am using WHMCS. You can find more info at http://www.whmcs.com/  You can put clients into it, separate by servers, keep track of products/services for each client, custom notes for the client or if they have multiple domains you can write notes for each domain on a client.

It can automate a lot of things but If you're looking to keep it private from your clients, just don't put their email as contact info :)

Also, http://www.clientexec.com/ is a competitor to WHMCS and I haven't used it but it may be worth looking into.

Comment: whmcs is A paid for app. It'd be noce to see some open source answers.

Answer (score 1):

Because @Mark W asked for some open source answers (well, at leas free), you have the following:

- [phpcoin](https://www.phpcoin.com/)
- [minibill](http://code.google.com/p/minibill/)
- [gplhost](http://www.gplhost.com/software-dtc.html)

But there is none like WHMCS